# Is there a way to draw geometric shapes on the JPanel of a form created in Intelli J Idea

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I just started using Intelli J Idea and one of my first projects is to plot some geometric forms to a JPanel of a GUI defined in a form. In the end I want to plot some graphs. I found a tutorial where a class extending the JPanel was defined and the paintCompontent() method was overloaded.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int y2 = (int)(40 * Math.random());
        Line2D  line = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 60, y2);
        Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(200, 120, 70, 30);
        Ellipse2D oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(400, 200, 40, 60);
        g2.draw(line);
        g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(rectangle);
        g2.setPaint(Color.ORANGE);
        g2.fill(oval);
    }
}
```

This would run fine if I use it together with this code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyPanel s = new MyPanel();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(s);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
    }
}
```

Then I tried combining this with a form I created using Intelli J Idea. And this is where I have problems. I would like to have a form with a button and a JPanel. When I press the button some geometric figures are being drawn on the JPanel defined in the form. I think my best try is like this:

```
public class MainWindow {
    private JPanel panelMain;
    private JButton buttonCalculate;
    private JPanel panelPlot;

    public MainWindow() {
        buttonCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panelPlot = new MyPanel();
                panelPlot.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                panelPlot.setSize(200, 200);
                panelPlot.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MyFirstGraphTool");
        f.setContentPane(new MainWindow().panelMain);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But simply saving my derived JPlane object to the bound property does not change anything. 
And also the setBackgroundColor() method does not change anything.

Do you know any tutorials or more detailed explanation of how this can be done?

EDIT: Please find below an image of the component tree.
[Component tree from Intelli J Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCr5r.png)

Thanks and kind regards,
David

Comment: You are never adding `panelPlot` to any container.

Comment: I added an image of the component tree of Intelli J. So the panelPlot should be inside the panelMain if I get this right. Or do I have to also add them in the code somehow? EDIT: As I just started using Intelli J and don't have much experience using Java with GUI it could be that I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made lots of mistakes in your code. I try to explain you, what's wrong.

```
public class MainWindow {
    private JPanel panelMain; // panelMain is not initialized, so when you try to add it to any window/panel, you'll get a NullPointerException
    private JButton buttonCalculate; // same as before. Also this button is not added to any container (window/panel)
    private JPanel panelPlot; // panel is not added to any container

    public MainWindow() {
        buttonCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panelPlot = new MyPanel();
                panelPlot.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                panelPlot.setSize(200, 200); // this code will not be honored because the layout manager will recalculate panel bounds.
                                             // use setPreferredSize instead.
                panelPlot.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MyFirstGraphTool");
        f.setContentPane(new MainWindow().panelMain);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the correct version of your class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * <code>MainWindow</code>.
 */
public class MainWindow {
    private JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();

    private JButton buttonCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    private JPanel panelPlot; // panel is not added to any container

    public MainWindow() {
        buttonCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panelPlot = new MyPanel();
                panelPlot.setOpaque(true);
                panelPlot.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                panelPlot.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                panelMain.add(panelPlot);
                panelMain.revalidate(); // cause layout manager to recalculate component bounds
            }
        });
        panelMain.add(buttonCalculate);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MyFirstGraphTool");
        f.setContentPane(new MainWindow().panelMain);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            int y2 = (int) (40 * Math.random());
            Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 60, y2);
            Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(200, 120, 70, 30);
            Ellipse2D oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(400, 200, 40, 60);
            g2.draw(line);
            g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            g2.setPaint(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(oval);
        }
    }
}
```

Please also read about [layout managers in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still don't know how to use the layout I designed in the GUI of Intelli J. Because the properties panelMain, buttonCalculate and panelPlot come from the Intelli J Form which is bound to this class. By re-initialising them with "panelMain = new JPanel()" I loose the design and have to add all the components again in code. Maybe I should not use the graphical GUI editor at all and do everything in code.

Comment: @Ragnos The problem is, that UI designers are very restrictive and understand only the UI, that was created by itself. And you cannot designe a UI, that change its content (like I made in my solution). I work with Swing about 18 years and newer used any designer (OK, when I've started, they was terrible).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will make the UI by myself in code then. Does not look too complicated.

Comment: Found a solution to my problem there: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003406579-Drawing-on-a-JPanel-of-a-form?page=1#community_comment_360000453099